# gmake: eval inside a recipe in function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to do such thing in a makefile for gmake:

```
GOALS := g1
define fun_one
    @echo "blabla"  #this causes an error - maybe can't be recognized as a recipe
endef

define fun_two
$(1):
$(eval $(call fun_one,$(1)))
endef

$(forech goal, $(GOALS), $(eval $(call fun_two,$(goal))))

all: ${GOALS}
```

As far as I understand, I can't define a part of a recipe outside a function that defines a rule, am I write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the first `eval`; it just tells Make to enact that line *while it's still parsing the definition of fun_one*. Eliminate the eval and the makefile will work:

```
define fun_two
$(1):
$(call fun_one,$(1))
endef
```

Comment: it doesn't help: error at the foreach line:

   "*** missing separator.  Stop."

When @echo "blabla" is commented - no errors

Comment: @Riga: I'll go out on a limb: that should be a TAB in `fun_one`, but I'll bet it's just spaces.